# I accidentally clicked something and the little bar at the bottom for animating takes up my whole screen

Tags: screencast

[image]

I clicked something and now my entire "Layout" section is completely taken up by the animation bar, I have tried to simply use my cursor at the top to drag it back down, but it doesn't seem to be responsive.

Comment: Edit: I closed something and now the little GUI at the top right of my screen (The one that shows you your current parts inside the workspace, light, camera ect.) Takes up my whole screen.

Comment: Edit again: I fixed it, it doesn't matter anymore.